# Wp_deregister_script() doesn't work

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Somewhere in the parent theme for which I'm creating a child theme, the following line is executed:

```
wp_enqueue_script('quovolver', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.quovolver.js','','',true);
```

I want to remove this script, so I added in the end of "footer.php":

```
wp_deregister_script('quovolver');
```

However it doesn't work as the script is still called. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Paste it into your themes functions.php
As you have said that you are working on a child theme, then paste this code into your child themes functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'deq_der_script', 100 );

function deq_der_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'quovolver' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'quovolver' );
}
```